# Starting word generator from specific index

Tags: c#, algorithm, math, combinatorics

I have a password list generator which generates all combinations of a specific set of characters for a specific length.
Naturally the list is very long and it takes quite a while to generate.

I want to parallelize the process but have ran into a algorithm/math problem.

Example, I want to generate all combinations of [a-z] (26 leters) for a 4 character long password.
The total count of combinations is 26^4  = 456.976

To parallelize into ex. two processes, I want a process to handle the first half and another to handle the second half. 228.488 combinations each.

And now to the question ...
The process which should handle the second half, hot to I get from the number 228.488 to the letter combination the generator should start with?

I'm looking for a general solution so if letter count or password length is changed, it will still work.
Of course this has been solved long ago, maybe it even has a name. I'm just not aware of that name and i'm not able to google it.

I'm implementing this in C#

Thanks.

Comment: Why not it be a random collection of characters(4 or n) each time.

Comment: That would inevitably lead to duplicates. Also the list should be exhaustive as it will be used for security penetration tests.

Comment: Hope that, userName will be unique and a combination of username and password will be used for authentication process, so duplicates may not be a problem in this scenario. And also, holding a `List<string>` having ` 4.503.599.627.370.496` will not be good even though you populate them through parallel process

Comment: I may be making a really dumb suggestion, but why not just start with the middle letter (13th)?

Comment: I think it is 26^4 instead of 4^26.

Comment: Eric, woops, you are right! Will edit my question. Thanks!

Comment: o_weisman: That's actually not a bad idea. It may not split the workload into completely equal sized pieces but that really does not matter in the longer run.

Comment: un_lucky: No data will be kept in memory while generating. Each process will persist directly to a file.

Comment: Do you currently have a way to generate these in a particular sequence? Could you modify this to just generate every nth element of the sequence? If both of these are yes, then you can start n processes at passwords 0..n-1 and have them each generate every nth password.

Comment: No data will be kept in memory while generating??? Are you going to perform 26^4 file writes?

Comment: o_weismann: Well, actually things are kept in memory. I'm flushing to disk once per 1 mio. generated word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are exploring the whole `[a-z]^4` space. There are `26^4` different elements in that space.

Just consider an element of `[a-z]^4` as a 4 digits number in base `26`. Given an integer `i` you can find its expression in base 26 and get the `word` you're looking for.

```
word[0] = i % 26
word[1] = (i / 26) % 26
word[2] = (i / 26 / 26) % 26
word[3] = (i / 26 / 26 / 26) % 26
```

If you have `M` machines, the machine at index `j` can start at index: `j*(26^4/M)`.

So if your machine start at index: `228488` it will begin by the word:

```
word[0] = 228488 % 26             = 0  => 'a'
word[1] = (228488 / 26) % 26      = 0  => 'a'
word[2] = (228488 / 26 / 26) % 26 = 0  => 'a'
word[3] = (228488 / 26 / 26 / 26) = 13 => 'm'
```

Comment: Awesome! and an extra thanks for adding details about M machines.